# 550 error when attempting to upload file via FTP in C# on remote server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

The below code works when run against a server in our internal network. When I change the credentials to reflect a server outside of our network, I get a 550 error in response. When I catch the exception like so:

```
try { 
    requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

}
catch(WebException e) {
    string status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
    throw e;
}
```

status has a value of:
"550 Command STOR failed\r\n"

I can successfully upload a file using the same credentials using a client such as Filezilla. I have already tried using SetMethodRequiresCWD() as other answers have suggested and this did not work for me.

Here is the code, which receives a list of strings that each contain a full path to a file.

```
private void sendFilesViaFTP(List<string> fileNames) {
    FtpWebRequest request = null;

    string ftpEndPoint = "ftp://pathToServer/";
    string fileNameOnly; //no path
    Stream requestStream;

    foreach(string each in fileNames){
        fileNameOnly = each.Substring(each.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

        request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpEndPoint + fileNameOnly);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        StreamReader fileToSend = new StreamReader(each);

        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileToSend.ReadToEnd()); //this is assuming the files are UTF-8 encoded, need to confirm
        fileToSend.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();


        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //validate this in some way?
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the path? Error 550 is basically a permission denied error (no such file or folder) error.

Comment: This code appears to have been copied and pasted from this MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715%28v=vs.110%29.aspx page (albeit with a foreach tweak). As @JunaidKirkire mentioned, the devil is in the detail - make sure your path information and configuration are all correct.

Comment: I have double checked the path, which matches the path that I see when connecting via Filezilla. I have also tried changing request.Method to WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory (omitting the file name to leave only the path) and this also returns error 550. I'm not saying that definitely isn't the problem, but it doesn't seem to be from what I am observing. Is it possible that there is another explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to resolve this using FtpWebRequest. I re-implemented using WebClient as below, which produced more concise code and had the side-benefit of working:

```
    private void sendFilesViaFTP(List<string> fileNames){
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        foreach(string each in fileNames){
            byte[] response = client.UploadFile("ftp://endpoint/" + each, "STOR", each);
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
            Console.Write(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue; for some reason using `FtpWebRequest` required me to use credentials for my FTP server with **full access to all folders and subfolders**, not just the folder I wanted to save to.

If I kept using the other credentials (which worked fine on other clients) I would repeatedly get the 550 error.

I would try another FTP user that has all access and see if that works.